# IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds when accessing pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to access values of data by indices (`xi` and `yi` should be row indices), but I get the error `IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds`.

```
for xi, yi in kd:
    X, y = data[xi], y_labs[yi]
```

- data is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
- kd is numpy.ndarray
- y_labs is numpy.ndarray

Comment: Obviously, the numbers stored in `kd` are not suitable indices for `data` and `y_labs`. Inspect how `kd` is created and what numbers it actually contains.

Comment: Probably an XY problem. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your empty dataframe with index, and then access its locations.
For instance

```
data = pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(yourFile)),columns = ['col1','col2'])
```

When you don't enter the index, `pandas` can't access cells or rows as there are not any.